# How to combine .java and html?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, web-crawler

I am trying to create a web application, where the user can pick a name of a movie (ex. "Skyfall") from a dropdown list. Then I want to execute a crawler to go to rottentomatoes.com and fetch all the html pages relating to this movie. I have created my web application (the GUI) in Eclipse using Tomcat. I have a web crawler: crawler4j, which runs if I choose to run the main .java file as an application. How can I combine these two?

1. Is it possible to call the java class file with the
   parameter (name of movie) from  html ?
2. Do I have to create a separate Applet with the crawler, in
   order to execute it within my html? Can I do that and send strings
   with that (the name of the movie  from the html 
   , so I need to send that with the crawler search)?

Comment: I'm confused - is this a website or a desktop application?  Are you using a Java App on the page, or just for the server?

Comment: @IceSun, you'd either have to a) run the Java code as an applet, which would be kind of complicated for a variety of reasons, or b) run the Java code on a server, such as in a servlet.  That takes you into J2EE territory, and it's a big topic.  There'd be other approaches as well.

Comment: Hi, I am not very experienced with development. But what I have learned so far is html and java for the most part ... but never together. That is why I am not going into learning PHP or JSON. I am developing a website.

Comment: @Marvo: I have heard about servlets ... does that mean that I would have to change my whole project, or I can keep it the same, using Tomcat, and create Servlet pages with the java code?   Sorry for the ignorance, but this is a first time for me in combining two ways to program ... and I am not a programmer :)

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet engine, so that is one approach.  (There's also Jetty or JBoss in the free-ish category, and a bunch in the expensive category.)  I don't know enough about your project to say if or what would need to be changed.  Servlets, servlet containers, and related technologies is a big topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by implementing a Servlet which activates the crawler, as Marvo suggested in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), I use it all the time to get content from other sites.

Or, you can also use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net)